# Selecting element by xPath vs. class vs. byId

Tags: automated-testing, selenium2, selenium-webdriver, xpath

Selenium WebDriver provides numerous ways to select an element as shown in [googledocs](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/remote/RemoteWebElement.html) (under "implements interfaces"):

- by class name
- by id
- by xpath
- etc.

Is there one that is more "resistant" (i.e. automated tests won't break) to changes in the application being developed and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answer already said, the preferred order is this:

1. ID Locator
2. NAME Locator
3. CSS Locator
4. XPATH Locator

However, the reason **why** is simple: an `ID` is supposed to be unique, so once you have a certain element with a specific identifier, this is unlikely to change. Also, no matter where the element is moved to on a page, the `ID` stays the same.

However, an XPath is more brittle: for example, if elements switch places in a `div` or `body` container (due to new elements being added, ...), the xpath might break.
Of course, you'll often have to rely on XPath or CssSelectors for dynamic or complex HTML.

**Conclusion**: try to get the developers to add as much `ID` and `name` elements as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have always been told this order when finding elements.

> 1. By ID
> 2. By CSS Selector
> 3. By XPath

This has served me well with my automation in the past, be especially careful with XPath.